# Why does animation pause on hover work in IE but not Chrome or Edge?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the HTML and CSS working to create a scrolling slideshow of 3 images in the same place. I want the animation to pause when I hover over any of the pictures and then just start up again where the animation left off when I stop the hover. The following code works in Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome or Edge. I need it to work in any browser. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```css
div.slideshow3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
div.slideshow3 figure {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
div.slideshow3:hover figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow3">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/2" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/3" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I had changed the `src` attribute value for all the three `img` tags because the original images are not accessible (they were relative to your site) and the modified values help users to see the problem much better. Please feel free to roll it back if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the behavior in Chrome and Edge is the correct one and this is probably why Microsoft has corrected the behavior in their latest browser.

The reason why it does not work is very simple. The hover selector (which pauses
the animation) has the same specificity as the other selectors which set the animation and in addition the other selectors are specified after the hover selector in the CSS file. This makes them get precedence over the hover selector at any point of time (even when the hover is on). Because of this, the `animation-play-state` never gets set to `paused` and so the animation keeps running.

Let us have a look at the specificity of the selectors one by one:

- `div.slideshow3:hover figure`
- The number of ID selectors in the above selector is 0 (so a = 0)
- The number of class/attribute/pseudo-class selectors in it is 2 (so b = 2)
- The number of type/pseudo-element selectors in it is 2 (so c = 2)
- So, its overall specificity is 022.
- `div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(1)`

  - The number of ID selectors in the above selector is 0 (so a = 0)
  - The number of class/attribute/pseudo-class selectors in it is 2 (so b = 2)
  - The number of type/pseudo-element selectors in it is 2 (so c = 2)
  - So, the overall specificity for this one is also 022 but it is specified later in the CSS file.

You can read more about CSS Selector Specificity [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

You can fix this issue in two ways and they are as follows:

- Move the `hover` selector below all the animation definition selectors. This makes the `hover` selector take precedence over the rest and so will pause the animation when the container is hovered on. This is the simplest solution.

```css
div.slideshow3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
div.slideshow3 figure {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3:hover figure {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow3">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/2" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/3" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
</div>
```

- The alternate would be to specify your hover selector as `div.slideshow3:hover figure:nth-child(n)`. This means there are 3 class/pseudo-class selectors in the selector and so specificity becomes higher than the others. `nth-child(n)` basically selects all and so that is not a problem.

```css
div.slideshow3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
div.slideshow3 figure {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
div.slideshow3:hover figure:nth-child(n) {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow3">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/2" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/3" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
</div>
```

**Note:** Even though, the `hover` selector takes precedence after doing one of the above changes, the animation still doesn't get paused in **Edge** alone. The changes mentioned above **does fix the issue in Chrome, Firefox, Safari** and it **works in IE11, IE10** also.

The behavior in Edge seems to be very erratic. If you open [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d5fyod23/1/) for the first time, the animation would be running and when you hover it will pause in Edge also but if you make any dummy changes to the code and click "Run" button, it no longer works. This is beyond explanation. I checked with few other fellow users in [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69317/css-shapes-svg-and-designs) and everybody sees the same behavior in Edge.

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to get this to work in Edge. I have tried a variety of selector combinations (even tried inline styles with JS) but it is just not respecting the animation's play state change at all. The **selector however is working perfectly fine**. In the below snippet, you'd be able to notice the `border` changing on hover but nothing happens to the animation.

```css
div.slideshow3 {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
div.slideshow3 figure {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
div.slideshow3:hover figure:nth-child(n) {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
  border: 4px solid brown; /* hover border */
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 10s infinite;
  border: 4px solid red; /* default border */
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 5s infinite;
  border: 4px solid red; /* default border */
}
div.slideshow3 figure:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
  animation: xfade3 15s 0s infinite;
  border: 4px solid red; /* default border */
}
@-webkit-keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes xfade3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  31.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  98% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow3">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/1" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/2" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/nature/3" style="width:300px; height:300px;">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both of the changes you suggested and got the same results as you. It works in Chrome but not in Edge. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AngelaVella: Unfortunately there seems to be no way to get this to work in Edge. I have tried a variety of selector combinations (even tried inline styles with JS) but it is just not respecting the animation's play state change at all. All other styles are getting applied properly (and overriding default styles on hover).

Answer (score -1):

In any browser you are going to have to work with different parameters as each browser is going to be different. That is something you will just have to accept. However, there are things that you can do to accommodate the different browsers. In order to force it to fit, from what I learned in my html class, you are going to have to adapt your h&w so that it fits within the every browser and then check every browser.

OR just understand that you cannot write a program, in html, to fit every browser.